# NumberFormatException error confusion on online editor (Java)

Tags: java

Zybooks keeps throwing this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "JaneAusten"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)

I have posted a picture of my code, thanks.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzeGU.jpg)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aeh3B.jpg)

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqg4q.jpg)

Comment: Why a picture of your code? I might want to test it, and then I have to transcribe your code, while you could make my life a lot easier and just post the code here. What do you think I'm going to do? Ignore your question or transcribe the code and try to help you?

Comment: @John3136 Definitely a 9

Comment: Please [don't post image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) and [format code and error messages as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and create a [mcve]. 3 images is definitely not a MCVE.

Comment: Make sure `dataString` **does in fact contain a valid string representation of a numerical value** and NOT a null string ("") or NOT a value that contains any characters other than digits 0 to 9. The **Integer.parseInt()** method must contain a string numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

provide the clear stack trace ,the first line is truncated..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "JaneAusten" at
```

Reason for exception is You are trying to convert a string "JaneAusten" to interger by API "Integer.parseInt".